# mysql error with LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: mysql

I Have an error when i use a MYSQL_INSERT_ID..

The error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO FicheHandicap (NumeroCORH) VALUES (NULL); SET
>   @NewidFicheHandicap =' at line 2

The request :

```
START TRANSACTION;
 INSERT INTO FicheHandicap (NumeroCORH) VALUES (NULL);
 SET @NewidFicheHandicap = LAST_INSERT_ID();
 INSERT INTO FicheSanitaire (DateVaccinHepatite) VALUES (NULL);
 SET @NewidFicheSanitaire = LAST_INSERT_ID();
 INSERT INTO Identite (Nom,NomJeuneFille,Prenoms,DateNaissance,LieuNaissance,Nationalite,CouvertureSociale,Mutuelle1,Mutuelle2,Mutuelle3,Bourse1,Bourse2,Sexe,idGenre,idFicheSanitaire,idFicheHandicap) VALUES ("TOTO","","TOTO","2013-06-12","TOTO","TOTO","TOTO","TOTO","TOTO","TOTO","TOTO","TOTO","0","1",@NewidFicheSanitaire,@NewidFicheHandicap);
 SET @NewidIdentite = LAST_INSERT_ID();
 INSERT INTO Personne (MembreActif, Actif, IdIdentite) VALUES ("1", "1", @NewidIdentite);
 COMMIT;
```

I use with php :

```
$query = 'START TRANSACTION;'."\n";
$query .= ' INSERT INTO FicheHandicap (NumeroCORH) VALUES (NULL);'."\n";
$query .= ' SET @NewidFicheHandicap = LAST_INSERT_ID();'."\n";
$query .= ' INSERT INTO FicheSanitaire (DateVaccinHepatite) VALUES (NULL);'."\n";
$query .= ' SET @NewidFicheSanitaire = LAST_INSERT_ID();'."\n";
$query .= ' INSERT INTO Identite (Nom,NomJeuneFille,Prenoms,DateNaissance,LieuNaissance,Nationalite,CouvertureSociale,Mutuelle1,Mutuelle2,Mutuelle3,Bourse1,Bourse2,Sexe,idGenre,idFicheSanitaire,idFicheHandicap) VALUES ("'.$resultat['Nom'].'","'.$resultat['NomJeuneFille'].'","'.$resultat['Prenoms'].'","'.preg_replace("#(.*)/(.*)/(.*)#", "$3-$2-$1", $resultat['DateNaissance']).'","'.$resultat['LieuNaissance'].'","'.$resultat['Nationalite'].'","'.$resultat['CouvertureSociale'].'","'.$resultat['Mutuelle1'].'","'.$resultat['Mutuelle2'].'","'.$resultat['Mutuelle3'].'","'.$resultat['Bourse1'].'","'.$resultat['Bourse2'].'","'.$resultat['Sexe'].'","'.$resultat['idGenre'].'",@NewidFicheSanitaire,@NewidFicheHandicap);'."\n";
$query .= ' SET @NewidIdentite = LAST_INSERT_ID();'."\n";
$query .= ' INSERT INTO Personne (MembreActif, Actif, IdIdentite) VALUES ("'.$resultat['MembreActif'].'", "'.$resultat['Actif'].'", @NewidIdentite);'."\n";
$query .= ' COMMIT;'."\n";

                $resultat = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the error.  How are you running these queries?

Comment: I edited my code, i use with php and class mysqli